# how to Improve The performance of code python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, performance, asynchronous

currenly in my code i am downloading the pdf(1 page has 10 pdf) and it has around 900 pages so 9000 pdf currently i am using `threading` and it is taking 1400 pdf in 1 hr pls help to improve my code

```
  import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def writepdf(k, v):
    path = r"C:\Users\deepak jain\Desktop\spectra"
    with requests.Session() as session:
        with open(f'{path}/{k}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            with session.get(v, stream=True) as r:
                for data in r.iter_content():
                    f.write(data)

def main():
    with requests.Session() as s:
        current_page = 1
        end_number = 900
        threads = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            while current_page <= end_number:
                r = s.get(f'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no={current_page}')
                r.raise_for_status()
                soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
                for i in soup.select('.bid_no > a'):
                    k = i.text.strip().replace('/', '_')
                    v = f'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in{i["href"]}'
                    threads.append(executor.submit(writepdf, k, v))
                if current_page == 1:
                    num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.pagination li:last-of-type > a')['data-ci-pagination-page'])
                    end_number = min(end_number, num_pages)
                current_page += 1
            for t in threads:
                t.result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I do not see any use of threading in this example.

Comment: You have two sections that are performing requests, but the first one is still being done sequentially, so there's some improvement that could be done there by also threading that.

Comment: Also, I have done enough async to know how to tell you to do it, but I know this type of web requesting pattern is a good candidate for it and could be the more performant than threading.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you have a number of pages containing links to pdf file. Your main thread parses the pages, and a number or working threads download the pdf files.

You use a ThreadPoolExecutor which looks reasonable.

Possible improvements at first sight:

- you wait the end of all working threads after each page(because the `for t in threads` loop is inside the main loop). Unless you have strong reasons for it, you should only wait at the end of the main loop (ie move the `for t in threads` loop outside of the main loop)
- you currently use the default number of threads in you `ThreadPoolExecutor`. When it comes to downloading files from internet, the lattency caused by the HTTP protocol can be high, and I would try to explicitely give that number of threads and tweak it to the best value. The default is 5 * number of processors which often ends to just 5. You could try values 5, 10, 15 and 20 (eventually more...) and see whether there is an improvement. Beware, some sites could see a high number of parallel downloads from the same source address as an attack, so be prepared to face connection errors with high values. If it happens wait a moment and try again with lower values.

Comment: could you pls edit the code with comment to help